# A way to customize <Switch /> color

Tags: react-native

[Switch](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/switch.html#switch) for iOS can take props that changes it's color. Is there really no way to do the same for Android?

Answer (score 3):

It's indeed not possible for now using the `Switch` component provided by React Native. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2903

However someone made a pure JavaScript implementation which is customizable: https://github.com/Recr0ns/react-native-material-switch

Comment: Thanks, that's a shame